# Cannot invoke because Array[] is null

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter, encapsulation

I'm still new to programming and I want to make a program that will take the food order from user until the user presses "n" to stop. But I can't seem to make it work like I want it to.

I want my output to be like this.

```
Buy food: Burger
Order again(Y/N)? y
Buy Food: Pizza
Order again(Y/N)? n

You ordered: 
Burger
Pizza
```

But my output right now is this.

```
Buy food: Burger
Order again(Y/N)? y
Buy food: Pizza
Order again(Y/N)? n

You ordered: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Array.getFoodName()" because "food_arr2[i]" is null
    at Food.main(Food.java:50)
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Food food = new Food();  
        Array[] food_arr;

        boolean stop = false;
        String foodName;
        int k = 1;
        int j = 0;
        
        while(stop == false) {
            food_arr = new Array[k];

            System.out.print("Buy food: ");
            foodName = s.next();
            food_arr[j] = new Array(foodName);
            food.setFoodArray(food_arr);

            System.out.print("Order again(Y/N)? ");
            String decide = s.next();
            if(decide.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                k++;
                j++;
            }
            else if(decide.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                stop = true;
            }
        }

        Array[] food_arr2 = food.getFoodArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < food_arr2.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println("\nYou ordered: ");
            System.out.println(food_arr2[i].getFoodName()); //This line is the error according to my output
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to fix this and I was hoping for someone to help me.

Comment: the error is coming because `food.getFoodArray()` is returning null.Why don't you try checking if it is null by `if(food.getFoodArray() == null)`?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal The exception does not indicate the array itself is null, it indicates the value at index i of the array (`foo_arr2[i]`) is null

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do with the k value setting the size of the array you are using.
However, with each iteration of the while loop:

```
food_arr = new Array[k];
```

Will create a new empty array each time!

So, for example, on the second iteration

```
food.setFoodArray(food_arr);
```

Will set foods array as something like [null, "Pizza"]

Even if this did work, creating a new array each time is not a very efficient method.

---

I would strongly recommend using a different, dynamically allocated data structure such as an ArrayList and defining it outside the scope of the while loop.

```
ArrayList<Food> food_arr = new ArrayList<Food>() 
// Note that I'm just guessing the data type here - I can't see what you are actually using!   

while(stop == false) {

        System.out.print("Buy food: ");
        foodName = s.next();
        food_arr.add(foodName)
        
        // etc, etc
    }

food.setFoodArray(food_arr) 
// ! Note: You will need to convert the array list into an array
// ! or change the data struture in the Food class

// etc, etc
```

However, this is just the first solution that popped into my head, check out different kinds of data structures and think about how else you could design this program yourself!